# Laravel testing: create a new user

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

I would like to test my sign up form in Laravel. I'm doing this:

```
$this->visit('/auth/signup/free')
        ->type('First Name', 'first_name')
        ->type('test-phpunit@example.org', 'email')
        ->type('mypassword', 'password')
        ->press('Get Started');
```

But I have an error 500, because I then redirect the user to a welcome page which test some property of the current user, and these ones doesn't exist:

```
A request to [http://localhost/welcome] failed. Received status code [500].
Caused by
exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined property: App\Models\User::$active' in D:\workspace\myproject\app\Models\User.php:48
Stack trace:
#0 D:\workspace\myproject\app\Models\User.php(48): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined prope...', 'D:\\workspace\\my...', 48, Array)
#1 D:\workspace\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(2670): App\Models\User->active()
[...]
```

The user appears in the database, but it seems that Laravel doesn't have access to any of its property.

How could I handle this?

Edit: I'm using Laravel 5.3. I have the same error than this guy: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/51-phpunit-tests-fail-without-middleware/replies/89708

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.3.

Answer (score 2):

Let me guess. You are probably observing error like accessing `/welcome` without authentication. Check if `/welcome` page gives such an error for an unauthorized request.

Googling [says (it is marked as a solution)](https://laravel.io/forum/04-14-2015-how-to-set-cookies-during-unit-test) that Laravel can have problem with encrypting cookies when testing. Try to disable `EncryptCookies` middleware for testing.

Dusk in Laravel 5.4 does behave like a real browser, it will probably help you.

Comment: I have a middleware on this page that redirects the user if not connected, so this appear should never appear. I tried to disable this middleware without success. The user is redirect to the welcome page because the we click on the "sign up" button, and we create the user, sign in him and redirect him directly.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

Actually, it depends on the Laravel version.

If you are using the latest version (5.4), then I think you inverted you `key => value`. 
Instead of

```
->type('test-phpunit@example.org', 'email')
```

Do

```
->type('email', 'test-phpunit@example.org')
```

For all of them.

Then, somewhere you need to assert something to see if the user was redirected to home page properly. e.g: `->assertPathIs('/home');`

If you are on 5.3, then your key values are alright. Just add an assertion at the end to see. Like: `->seePageIs('/welcome');`

Comment: Laravel docs say `->type('Taylor', 'name')`. So he uses it correctly.

Comment: I guess, he uses 5.3 or older, not dusk.

Comment: You are right, I just updated my answer. @shukshin.ivan, if you can help him, just put an answer, I will just delete mine if it doesnt help the OP.

Comment: I'm using 5.3, the order is correct and the user is well redirected. Just when redirected I got this error and can't do any assert.